# Magento - How to swap the add to cart form to my own form

Tags: magento

I am writing a module that hides the add to cart button and price (product view) and displays a short form (contact us kind of thing) in its place (based on a product attribute).

Because there is a form that wraps up most of the important info on the product view page I can’t simply inject my own phtml file with its own form because that would leave nested forms.
So it now looks like I have to override the entire catalog/product/view.phtml file with my own just to change the form action. Like so:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mycompany/mymodule/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>    
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then within my view file I change the form action accordingly.

```
$formAction = $this->getSubmitUrl($_product);
if($_product->getData("myattribute")){
    $formAction = $this->getBaseUrl().'mycontroller/';
}

<form action="<?php echo $formAction ?>" ...[snip]
```

This seems like massive overkill just to change a forms action.

The way I see it I have 2 options:

1)  Add some javascript to my submit button onclick event that changes the default form action to go to my controller. This way hijacking the add to cart form. (But this will have issues if javascript is disabled)

2)  Have an observer that checks every single add to cart event to see if it needs to add to the cart or should process my form instead. (The form will be displayed on the product page if needed)

(At the moment I’m not thinking about integrating with custom themes etc…I just want to get my head around one thing at a time! - Well ok, maybe one eye on custom themes..)

Can anyone suggest a better or more efficient way to achieve this? Or if not which option would you recommend, 1 or 2?

Thanks

Comment: If at all possible, keep your custom theme tweaks to a minimum. Best to buy one that's close to what you're looking for and keep tweaks as specific and narrow as possible. I had someone help with my Magento install and they did way too many tweaks to the templates. :( Now I'm having to start from scratch updating from 1.4.2 to 1.5 or 1.6.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but when I say custom themes I mean other peoples themes that may be installed on their Magento installations. So I would need my module to work for "out of the box" when installed through Magento Connect. Although its looking like, for this particular issue, it's never going to be 100% compatible with all themes.

Comment: Also on a side note Chris, don't be too tough on the dev that built your custom theme. After all, a developer can't see in to the future and know what core changes will be implemented in future versions of magento. Unfortunately that's just one of the "fun" parts of magento development :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the massive overkill method sounds like the best route to go. You get the change in form action that you wanted and it looks to be Magento friendly.

If you really don't want to do that, then I would recommend going with option two. You do not want to rely on the entire internet having Javascript enabled when they visit your site (the overall percentage of people who have this disabled will be very small, but they could be a massive thorn in your side).

Comment: That’s a shame. I was hoping there may be a method which I’d missed! Because overriding the view.phtml file will probably cause major headaches with custom themes as it’s one of the files that always gets changed in a theme (I know I said I wasn’t thinking about custom themes but you’ve got to have 1 eye on them right?!)

Comment: Changing themes altogether hopefully is not something you do often, but it is good to make sure that you are thinking about those kinds of things. We tend to have our theme and when we need to make changes, we change that theme. We have never had to switch to a different theme [yet].

Comment: True but if I wanted to release this as a module it's something I need to think about. Thanks